# tweetnacl api and different key pairs

Tags: c, digital-signature, public-key-encryption

The [tweetnacl library](http://tweetnacl.cr.yp.to/) provides two functions to generate public and secret key pairs: `crypto_box_keypair(pk,sk);` and `crypto_sign_keypair(pk,sk);`:

1. The first function initializes key pairs which are intended to be used to
   encrypt messages using the `crypto_box(c,m,mlen,n,pk,sk);` API and to
   decrypt these later using the `crypto_box_open(c,n,pk,sk)` function.
   Good example code seems to be hard to find.  [Here is one](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/public-key_cryptography/authenticated_encryption.html) for 
   the library [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium) which is as tweetnacl based on NaCl.
2. The second function however initializes a keypair which can be used to 
   sign a message using the `crypto_sign(sm,&smlen,m,mlen,sk);` API and 
   later verify the signature using `crypto_sign_open(m,&mlen,sm,smlen,pk);`

While looking at the key generation code I figured out that in both cases the key generation starts with a 256 bit random number but yields different 
public keys in the end.  In fact the returned 512 bit signing `sk` key contains a copy of the public key `pk` in its so to say *upper half*.

I've looked through all documentation I could find which is not much.
Currently I've come to the conclusion that there is no proper way to use the same single key pair for both facilities.  Am I right?

Comment: Using a key for multiple purposes can open up your system to serious attacks. Always use a key for its intended *single* purpose.

Comment: The background of this question is: To establish trust into a public key received from someone else it is necessary to verify that this is original public key (by some other means).  For example the owner of the key could write a hexadecimal representation of it down on paper and give it to somebody.  Of course this is a difficult procedure.  So it would be helpful if such a key pair could be used for both kinds of operation like for example in PGP.

Comment: Or you could generate both key pairs for two different use cases, which is the [right thing to do](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/8563/45523).

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same kind of keypairs. The key generation for both may start with a 32-byte seed, but the relationship between the generated public and private keys in the two types of keypairs are different, so you cannot use them interchangeably. The fact that the private signing key contains its public key has no bearing on this matter.